# Could not activate iPhone because "activation server cannot be reached"

Tags: ios, iphone, activation-lock

I just purchased an iPhone 5s and attached to my iCloud. After that it seems that App Store applications were not installing properly. I did a factory reset and the following screen is shown:

> Could Not Activate iPhone
>
> Your iPhone could not be activated because the activation server cannot be reached. Try connecting your iPhone to iTunes to activate it, or try again in a few minutes.
>
> If this problem persists, contact Apple Support at apple.com/uk/support
>
> Try Again

[image]

Comment: ...and did you contact Apple support at the given URL?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to either connect to iTunes to activate or take the device to another network (or perhaps both).

Hopefully it isn’t an issue with the device itself but you’ll need to work through the support links provided for sure if a second network connection fails you as well.

Comment: Often times its the network. He should change the network hes using for now.

Comment: So well stated, @MelvinJefferson I've edited the main answer on the linked question to explain / reinforce that message here and there.